# Is there currently a way to run Blazor bUnit tests from within the GitLab CI Pipeline?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, bunit

We have a Microsoft .NET Blazor server-side application. We have incorporated [bUnit](https://bunit.dev/) testing that triggers when we run the Blazor app from within VisualStudio.

Recently, we have been asked to use GitLab for our CI/CD.

As I am new to GitLab and bUnit, itself, is fairly new, I am not sure how to accomplish this.

In VisualStudio, in order to create and run bUnit tests, we had to have a structure like so:

```
OurProject/
∟ BlazorProject/
  ∟ BlazorProject.csproj
  ∟ BlazorProject.sln
∟ bUnitTests/
  ∟ bUnitTests.csproj
```

I'm not even sure how to, or if it is possible, to run these tests from PowerShell. I add this part as the GitLab `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is essentially running command line commands to accomplish the tasks.

So, does anybody know how to accomplish running bUnit test from within the GitLab CI pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the test project like you normally do, e.g. via `dotnet test`.

Looks like this template is a good starting point: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/dotNET-Core.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I checked out the documentation at GitLab.com, but I couldn't find anything specific to bUnit (I assumed because it was relatively new), so I moved on.